# Incorrect Job configuration for violations plugin using Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to enable the violations and the Checkstyle option only in my "Build Settings" section of my Jenkins job and below is the code snippet :

```
  publishers {
    violations(100)    
    checkstyle('') {
        }
    }
```

It works fine but the violations and checkstyle configurations gets generated on the "Post-Build Actions" section rather in "Build Settings" section.

I'm looking to configure my job like below :
[image: Expected Job configuration]

but I'm getting the Job configuration like below:

[image]

Is it possible to just the enable the 'violations' and 'Publish CheckStyle Analysis Results' checkboxes on the **"Build Settings"** section of my Job ONLY.

Jenkins Version - 2.32.2

Job DSL - 1.57

violations plugin - 0.7.11

Checkstyle plugin - 3.47

P.S. I did a restart too after I installed the above plugins but the same problem.

Any advise pls. Thanks.

Comment: My Jenkins installation does not have a "Build Settings" tab, so it's probably provided by a plugin. Do you know which plugin that is?

Comment: @daspilker : You're right, it comes from the Maven Release plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) and the "Build Settings" tab is specific for Maven Jobs only.

I'm not sure how to leverage the configure block for that plugin to achieve my reqyirement. Any inputs please.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for the "Build Settings" section of the Maven job type is not built-in. You need to use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block):

```
mavenJob('example') {
  configure {
    it / reporters << 'hudson.plugins.violations.hudson.maven.ViolationsMavenReporter' {
      config {
        typeConfigs {
          entry {
            string('checkstyle')
            'hudson.plugins.violations.TypeConfig' {
              type('checkstyle')
              min(10)
              max(999)
              unstable(999)
              usePattern(false)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your valuable insight, I leveraged it for e-mail as well as checkstyle configuration too. Now I realise the power of Configure Block. Thanks again